# How to make child li elements become parent on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, navigation

On my site, there is a dropdown menu within the navigation, on mobile browsers I would like this dropdown to be expanded automatically(basically act as parent elements). Currently I have it set up so that the dropdown has a class that is hidden on mobile and then I have duplicated the dropdown LIs and added a class to them so that they only show on mobile and hide on desktop.

I was wondering if there was an easier way of doing this without duplicating the HTML code. Here is my current code to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
<ul id="mobileMenu">

    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/beer">Beer</a></li>
    <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-dropdown="connectmenu">Connect</a>
        <ul id="connectmenu" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
            <li><a href="/join">Join us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="/volunteer">Volunteer</a></li>
            <li><a href="/donate">Donate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="mobile-only"><a href="/join">Join us</a></li>
    <li class="mobile-only"><a href="/news">News</a></li>
    <li class="mobile-only"><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="mobile-only"><a href="/volunteer">Volunteer</a></li>
    <li class="mobile-only"><a href="/donate">Donate</a></li>

</ul>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function display_menu() {
    if (jQuery(window).width()<768) {
        jQuery(".mobile-only").show();
        jQuery(".dropdown").hide();

    } else {
        jQuery("#mobileMenuRight").show();
        jQuery(".mobile-only").hide();
        jQuery(".dropdown").show();

    }
}
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    display_menu();
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    display_menu();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope this was some sort of freak accident upon pasting to SO but please fix `<li class="<a href="index.php">Home</a></li>`

Comment: Why don't you just add/remove `class="mobile"` and set the css up to always show `.dropdown ul li`, I assume it is hidden in normal view since you did not supply any css

Comment: Yes, that was an accident MonkeyZeus :P and thanks for the suggesting Jammykam, I will give that a shot.